# Linq GroupBy Clause

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

```
var result = rows.GroupBy(x => new { y = x["AcademicYearId"] })
    .Select(
        g => new
        {
            AcademicYearId = g.Key.y,
            ClassGroups = g.GroupBy(x => new { y = x["ClassName"], h = x["ClassGroupId"], i = x["ClassYearId"] })
            .Select(
                classYear => new
                {
                    ClassName = classYear.Key.y,
                    ClassGroupId = classYear.Key.h,
                    ClassYearId=classYear.Key.i,
                    ClassDivisions = classYear.GroupBy(x => new { b = x["Division"], a = x["DivisionId"] })
                    .Select(
                    clsDiv => new
                    {
                        DivisionId = clsDiv.Key.a,
                        Division = clsDiv.Key.b                               
                    })
                })
        });
```

This is working code, but I want the "ClassDivisions" as orderBy Division.  What do I do for that?

Comment: you need add [`.OrderBy(a=>a.Division)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
var result =
    rows
        .GroupBy(x => new { y = x["AcademicYearId"] })
        .Select(g => new
        {
            AcademicYearId = g.Key.y,
            ClassGroups =
                g
                    .GroupBy(x => new { y = x["ClassName"], h = x["ClassGroupId"], i = x["ClassYearId"] })
                    .Select(classYear => new
                    {
                        ClassName = classYear.Key.y,
                        ClassGroupId = classYear.Key.h,
                        ClassYearId=classYear.Key.i,
                        ClassDivisions =
                            classYear
                                .GroupBy(x => new { b = x["Division"], a = x["DivisionId"] })
                                .Select(clsDiv => new
                                {
                                    DivisionId = clsDiv.Key.a,
                                    Division = clsDiv.Key.b                               
                                })
                                .OrderBy(clsDiv => clsDiv.Division)
                    })
        });
```